# Is there a way to converting matlab codes to latex?

Tags: matlab

I have some complicated codes and I want to convert them in equation format.

After that, I will write them using LaTeX.

I am sharing following part of code:

```
Dx = hypot(bsxfun(@minus,x,x'),bsxfun(@minus,y,y'));
```

Comment: Take a look at the `minted` package, if you want to automatically generate nicely formated source code from your `.m` files. If that's not what you seek to do, please clarify.

Comment: I do not understand at all what you want to do, could you try to elaborate/clarify?

Answer (score 4):

The Matlab function `latex` converts symbolic functions to LaTeX code (see https://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/latex.html).

For your example, `latex(Dx)` returns

```
\sqrt{\left|{x - \overline{x}}\right|^{2} + \left|{y - \overline{y}}\right|^{2}}
```

which renders as

[image]

Note that you need to declare the variables first (i.e., `syms x y`).

In case your function is not symbolic, then you need to declare the variables and convert the function using `symfun`:

```
>> syms q w
>> Ax = @(q, w) sqrt (q .^ 2 + w .^ 2);
>> g = symfun(Ax,[q w])
>> latex(g)
\sqrt{q^{2} + w^{2}}
```

Comment: I tried but following error message was appeared. Undefined function 'latex' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: The function is part of the Symbolic Math Toolbox (for Matlab, or the `symbolic` package for Octave). You may need to install and load this toolbox first. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240367/undefined-function-function-name-for-input-arguments-of-type-double/.